# Google Apps Script [Form Response Data]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have made a form to capture 2 data.
1) Email address.
2) Group which user wants to subscribe to.

Each group has their own spreadsheet.

When a user submits the form, the form should capture the email address, and sends the data to the respective spreadsheet which the user subscribed to.

This is what I've done so far. I'm stuck..

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];

      // Checks if it is multiple choice option
      if (itemResponse.getItem().getType() == FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {

        // If user chooses group 1, open spreadsheet and store user's email in 1st column
        if (itemResponse.getResponse() == "1") {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id goes here");
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Group subscription email");
        }
      }


    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is not happening that you want to happen?  How to match the choice in the form to what spreadsheet to write to?

If so, you can hard code a object of all your spreadsheet IDs and match them to a form choice.

```
var objOfSpreadsheetIDs = {"1":"oicjo0948t09afoa", "2":"498hnxoiv7r6gahauvgi", "3":"uuiocvgofhgeoyuih"};       
Logger.log("Check my object: " + objOfSpreadsheetIDs["3"])
```

So, your code might look something like this:

```
var objOfSpreadsheetIDs = {"1":"oicjo0948t09afoa", "2":"498hnxoiv7r6gahauvgi", "3":"uuiocvgofhgeoyuih"};

// If user chooses group 1, open spreadsheet and store user's email in 1st column
var whatGroupUserChoose = itemResponse.getResponse();
var whatSS_ID = objOfSpreadsheetIDs[whatGroupUserChoose];

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(whatSS_ID);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Group subscription email");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But when I get itemResponse.getResponse(), the first loop only gives me the group response. The 2nd loop gives me the email. So I don't know how to store both data properly.